# What's a good choice of steak to use for a steak pizza?

Tags: pizza, steak

I'm planning to cut into small cubes and place raw on the pizza before putting it into the oven. I wondering what cut of steak would be good for this purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any meat that is good for fast cooking (BBQ, frying, grilling etc.) will be suitable for this. Do not use meat that is normally casseroled or slow cooked. For beef this is the non-exercised top parts of the cow. Typical western cuts are called sirloin, rump, and fillet

You need very thin slices of meat more than cubes if you want any level of browning and cooking to be achieved

The easiest way to do this is to partially freeze you meat for one to two hours in a normal domestic freezer. A slab of meat with a profile of around 30 x 80 mm (±50%) is the easiest to handle. Use a sharp chef's knife or meat cleaver and slice it into 2 to 3 mm thin slices which will cook very nicely on a pizza

[image: Thin sliced beef]

A well marbled (mixed fat content) cut would work better, like in this picture

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed response.  What does the freezing do?  I was worried that with thin slices, the meat would overcook.  I normally cook my pizza for 5-6 mins at the maximum temperature (250 degrees celcius) of a normal domestic oven.

Comment: @deltanovember If it's partially frozen, it's easier to slice. If it's completely frozen it's too hard, and if it's not frozen at all, it's squishy and really difficult to cut straight.

Comment: @deltanovember As Jefromi says, easier to slice if partially frozen. It would over cook if it wasn't sitting on a cold slab of pizza dough coated in sauce, cheese, etc. Same way a slice of salami doesn't burn on a pizza. If the meat slice are on the top of the pizza you should have a nice grilled top, with a medium rare base in the slices

Comment: If you live by an Asian grocery store you might find frozen thinly sliced beef usually for hot pot...